# angularjs function failing because of extra $$hashKey

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the below HTML:

```
        <li ng-click="toggleBeep(beep)" ng-class-odd="'gradient-two'" 
            ng-class-even="'gradient-three'" ng-repeat="beep in beeps">
            <span>{{beep.name}}</span>
            <label class="bold" ng-show="isSelected(beep)">selected</label>
        </li>
```

JavaScript (AngularJS):

```
 $scope.beeps = $sounds.getAll();

        // get stored beep from localStorage
        var notification_beep =
            angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('notification_beep'));


        console.log($scope.beeps[0]);

        console.log(notification_beep);

        // handle change sound on click event
        $scope.toggleBeep = function (beep) {
            $cbSounds.play(beep.file);
            $scope.selected = beep;
            localStorage.setItem('notification_beep', angular.toJson(beep));
        };

        $scope.isSelected = function (beep) {
            return $scope.selected === beep;
        };
```

Now, when I click on any `li` I get the selected `label` is shown because of the `$scope.isSelected` function. However, when I try to add this line `$scope.selected = notification_beep` which is the beep object stored in the localStorage the `label` is not shown and I get the below return values.

[image: Objects returned in the console]
The only difference I could spot is that $$hashkey is present on `$scope.beeps[0]` while it's not on `notification_beep`. Could this be the cause? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think I need to invoke isSelected after I change $scope.selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comparison:

```
$scope.selected === beep
```

Will only return true if the two variables reference the same object.

The following line will create a new object:

```
var notification_beep = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('notification_beep'));
```

So it will not reference the same object as `$scope.selected`.

To clarify, this will return `false`: `{ name: 'Beep 1' } === { name: 'Beep 1' }`

The simplest solution is to instead compare against a unique primtive of the objects.

For example:

```
return $scope.selected.name === beep.name;
```

The `$$hashkey` property is inserted into the object by `ng-repeat` and is used to track which object corresponds to which DOM template. The reason it doesn't exist in `notification_beep` is because `angular.toJson` removes the property from the object.